# C++ template runtime choices

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to improve the following runtime template selection code:

We have 4 functors for p-norm calculation (1 general case, 3 specialized cases). During runtime, we can select the best one.

```
template <typename T>
struct p_norm { // contains functors to calculate p-norm
    struct general { ... }; // general case
    struct one { ... };     // specialize for p=1
    struct two { ... };     // specialize for p=2
    struct inf { ... };     // specialize for p=inf
};
```

For example, we can get the distance based on p,

```
auto impl_fptr = distance_fn<T, p_norm<T>::general>;
if (p == 1.0) {
  impl_fptr = distance_fn<T, p_norm<T>::one>;
} else if (p == 2.0) {
   impl_fptr = distance_fn<T, p_norm<T>::two>;
} else if (std::isinf(p)) {
   impl_fptr = distance_fn<T, p_norm<T>::inf>;
}
impl_fptr(vec1, vec2);
```

or maybe get the angle based on p,

```
auto impl_fptr = angle_fn<T, p_norm<T>::general>;
if (p == 1.0) {
  impl_fptr = angle_fn<T, p_norm<T>::one>;
} else if (p == 2.0) {
   impl_fptr = angle_fn<T, p_norm<T>::two>;
} else if (std::isinf(p)) {
   impl_fptr = angle_fn<T, p_norm<T>::inf>;
}
impl_fptr(vec1, vec2);
```

The problem is that there are a lot of code duplications in selecting a suitable template case. I have no clue on how to improve the type selection.

OTOH, the minor problem is that I would like to implement `p_norm<double>` for the general case and implement `p_norm<1.>, p_norm<2.>, ...` for template specialization. I know it's not how the template works, but is there any way to make the specialization more obvious? Probably via tag dispatching?

Comment: There seems to be a (possibly fundamental) misunderstanding, here. Template specialization works at **compile time**, not at run time.

Comment: I know that the specialization works at compile-time.

Comment: The specialization is meant for special optimized implementation.
Thus, during runtime, I would like to select a more optimized version.

Comment: What do you consider to be the set of possible values of `p`?\

Comment: p is double, p>=1 and p could be inf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) with tag ([`std::type_identity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity) here) might help:

```
template <typename T>
std::variant<std::type_identity<p_norm <T>::general>,
             std::type_identity<p_norm <T>::one>,
             std::type_identity<p_norm <T>::two>,
             std::type_identity<p_norm <T>::inf>>
get_method_var(double d)
{
    if (d == 1.0) { return std::type_identity<p_norm <T>::one>{}; }
    else if (d == 2.0) { return std::type_identity<p_norm <T>::two>{}; }
    else if (std::isinf(d)) { return std::type_identity<p_norm <T>::inf>{}; }
    else { return std::type_identity<p_norm <T>::general>{}; }
}
```

and then

```
template <typename T>
auto distance(const auto& vec1, const auto& vec2, double p)
{
    return std::visit([&](auto tag){
            return distance_fn<T, typename decltype(tag)::type>(vec1, vec2);
        }, get_method_var<T>(p));
}

template <typename T>
auto angle(const auto& vec1, const auto& vec2, double p)
{
    return std::visit([&](auto tag){
            return angle_fn<T, typename decltype(tag)::type>(vec1, vec2);
        }, get_method_var<T>(p));
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I want. Thank you and I have learned C++ a bit more.